# Get process by name in VB6

Tags: c#, process, vb6

I want to find a prosses ID by its name and wait for its finish to continue...
Right now I just try to get this prosses by name and its not work for me...

I have try to use this example

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20480608/Get-All-process-exe-names-in-Visual-Basic-6-0.html

But I got 0 from GetProcesses method

for example in C#
I write this code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = Process.GetProcessesByName("PulserTester").First().Id;
        }
    }
```

this code work just fine and returned Id 87068 I have run this both program on the same time now on debugging so I am sure that the PulserTester program is run...

```vb
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long



Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal Handle As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwDesiredAccessas As Long, _
ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
ByVal dwProcId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function EnumProcesses Lib "psapi.dll" (ByRef lpidProcess As Long, _
ByVal cb As Long, _
ByRef cbNeeded As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleFileNameExA Lib "psapi.dll" (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
ByVal hModule As Long, _
ByVal ModuleName As String, _
ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function EnumProcessModules Lib "psapi.dll" (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
ByRef lphModule As Long, _
ByVal cb As Long, _
ByRef cbNeeded As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub ExitProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uExitCode As Long)


Public Function GetProcesses(strProcess As String) As Long

 Dim lProcCount     As Long
 Dim lProcPoss      As Long
 Dim lNum           As Long
 Dim ProcessIDs()   As Long
 Dim cbNeeded2      As Long
 Dim NumElements2   As Long
 Dim arrModules(1 To 200) As Long
 Dim lRet           As Long
 Dim sModName       As String
 Dim hwndProcess    As Long
 Dim iCounter       As Long

 Const SIZE = 500
 Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 1024
 Const PROCESS_VM_READ = 16
 Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF

 'need to get the array containing the process id's for each process object

 lProcCount = 8
 lProcPoss = 96
 Do While lProcCount <= lProcPoss
     lProcCount = lProcCount * 2
     ReDim ProcessIDs(lProcCount / 4) As Long
     lRet = EnumProcesses(ProcessIDs(1), lProcCount, lProcPoss)
 Loop
 lNum = lProcPoss / 4

 For iCounter = 1 To lNum
     'Get a handle to the Process
     hwndProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, ProcessIDs(iCounter))
     'Got a Process handle
     If hwndProcess <> 0 Then
         'Get an array of the module handles for the specified
         'process
         lRet = EnumProcessModules(hwndProcess, arrModules(1), 200, cbNeeded2)
         'If the Module Array is retrieved, Get the ModuleFileName
         If lRet <> 0 Then
             sModName = Space(255)
             lRet = GetModuleFileNameExA(hwndProcess, arrModules(1), sModName, SIZE)
             'Form1.lstProcesses.AddItem ProcessIDs(iCounter) & vbTab & Left(sModName, lRet)
             If UCase(Left(sModName, lRet)) = UCase(strProcess) Then
                 GetProcesses = GetProcesses + 1
             End If
         End If
     End If
     'Close the handle
     lRet = CloseHandle(hwndProcess)
 Next

End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ShellExecute Me.hWnd, "open", "C:\Users\hed-b\Desktop\PulserTester.appref-ms", vbNullString, "C:\", ByVal 1&

    MsgBox GetProcesses("PulserTester")
End Sub
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In short I try to write the equivalent code to this code
from C# to VB6

```
var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe")
            {
                Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\hed-b\Desktop\PulserTester.appref-ms"
            };
            p.Start();
            while(Process.GetProcessesByName("PulserTester").Any() == false)
            { Thread.Sleep(100); }
            p = Process.GetProcessesByName("PulserTester").First();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Use VB6's Shell command which returns a task id. Or use `Wsh.run` which waits for the program to exit.

Comment: @CatCat
The problem with it its PulserTester.appref-ms do not run the PulserTester.exe
It's run a program that runs the PulserTester.exe so I have nothing to do with ID of PulserTester.appref-ms because it runs for a short time and just runs the program that runs PulserTester.exe

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `EnumProcessModules` and the fact that it's quite limited if you're running (as you almost certainly are) as 32-bit? Also, those `EnumXxx` functions give you a return value that *tells you how big your array needs to be*. You should jump straight to that value rather than playfully doubling your size in a potentially long loop.

Answer (score 1):

`txtnote.seltext` is something you can write too. Here's it's an edit control but it could be a filestream.

```vb
  Private Declare Function Process32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
  Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal Handle As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function Process32First Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
  Private Declare Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal th32ProcessID As Long) As Long

  Private Type PROCESSENTRY32
     dwSize As Long
     cntUsage As Long
     th32ProcessID As Long           ' This process
     th32DefaultHeapID As Long
     th32ModuleID As Long            ' Associated exe
     cntThreads As Long
     th32ParentProcessID As Long     ' This process's parent process
     pcPriClassBase As Long          ' Base priority of process threads
     dwFlags As Long
     szExeFile As String * 260 ' MAX_PATH
  End Type

   Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 1024
   Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ = 16
   Private Const MAX_PATH = 260
   Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = &HF0000
   Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
  'STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED Or SYNCHRONIZE Or &HFFF
   Private Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
   Private Const TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = &H2&
   Private Const hNull = 0


Sub mnuInsertProcessList_Click()
         Dim f As Long, sName As String, PList As String, Ret As Long
         Dim hSnap As Long, proc As PROCESSENTRY32
         hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)
         If hSnap = hNull Then Exit Sub
         proc.dwSize = LenB(proc)
         ' Iterate through the processes
         txtNote.SelText = "PID:int" & vbTab & "ParentPID:int" & vbTab & "ExeName:string" & vbCrLf
         f = Process32First(hSnap, proc)
         Do
                sName = Left(proc.szExeFile, InStr(sName, Chr(0)) - 1) ' Only the part that comes before the first Chr(0) character is the name, so use only the string that comes before the first Chr(0)
                txtNote.SelText = proc.th32ProcessID
                txtNote.SelText = vbTab
                txtNote.SelText = proc.th32ParentProcessID
                txtNote.SelText = vbTab
                txtNote.SelText = sName
                txtNote.SelText = vbCrLf
                f = Process32Next(hSnap, proc)
         Loop While f = 1
        Ret = CloseHandle(hSnap)
        If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox Err.LastDllError
 End Sub
```